# Counter variable not incrementing when accessing it in Groovy JSR223 Sampler

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jsr223

I have a simple loop controller and within it, a Counter config element, and a JSR223 Sampler running Groovy code. My Counter is set to begin at 0, increment by 1 up to a max of 3, and is set to a variable named 'idx'.

In my JSR223 Sampler, I log the value of idx using `log.info(${idx});` -- it always prints the first iteration value (in my case 0), for every loop iteration.

I disabled this JSR223 sampler and added a BeanShell sampler, doing the same log statement, `log.info(${idx});`, and it is incrementing properly -- I get the values 0, 1, 2 for the iteration.

I need to take some JSON, map them to objects, do some tweaking, then map them back to JSON. There are JSONParser, JSONObject, and JSONArray classes that seem to be working in the BeanShell Sampler, but I'm much more comfortable with Groovy's JsonSlurper and JsonBuilder classes and would prefer to use these.

All of these steps are within a Test Fragment, if that makes a difference. Anyone have any ideas? Is this a bug?

Comment: What version of Jmeter are you using? did you try to use this with groovy? `String x = vars.get("idx"); log.info(x);` its working fine with me.

Comment: Wow, that worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

**Never** refer [JMeter Function or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) directly in scripts, either use "Parameters" section for this like:

[image: JMeter Groovy Parameters]

Or use `vars` shorthand which stands for JMeterVariables class instance like:

```
log.info(vars.get('idx'))
```

[image: JMeter Groovy Vars Print Value]

The reasons are in:

- Function or variable may resolve into something which will cause compilation failure or unexpected behaviour
- Referencing variables and/or functions prevents caching compiled Groovy scripts so it negatively impacts performance
- Referencing functions and/or variables might conflict with [Groovy GString Template](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/text/GStringTemplateEngine.html)

See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more information on using Groovy scripting with [JSR223 Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) in JMeter tests.